# Angular JS RouteProvider does not call

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on an e-commerce like webapp to learn Angular. I have a menu on my home page (common and visible on all pages), which provides available products for e.g. Books, Clothes etc.

On my menu I have list items as follows:

`<li><a href="#/SearchProducts" ng-click="searchProduct('Computers')">Computers</a></li>
<li><a href="#/SearchProducts" ng-click="searchProduct('Academics Professional')">Academics & Professional</a></li>`

searchProduct function in my first controller sets the selected product in scope and sets the location.path.

```
$scope.searchProduct =function(productTBSearched){      
            $scope.TBFProduct=productTBSearched;
            $location.path("/SearchProducts");
        }
```

I also have route provider in my first controller which refers to another html and 2nd controller.

```
$routeProvider.when("/SearchProducts", {                
    templateUrl: "./views/HomeSearchProducts.html" ,
    controller: "productSearchCtrl"
});
```

In my second controller, I call a REST WS to search DB and build my Response JSON. The issue is when I click on the first item on menu at home page, I get search results and I can see my URL gets changed to  ".......Index2.html#/SearchProducts"

Now at this page when I try to choose another menu item, Routeprovider does not call the "ProductSearchCtrl" again and no Ajax call is executed for newly selected item. Could anyone help on this?

Comment: Firstly, there is no point using ng-click and href together

Comment: Thanks Nikhil. It does make sense. I have removed href, but I am still having same issue.

Comment: I have added a solution. Please see if it fits your need.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to reload the route. You can update your code to something like below in order to reload the route.

```
$scope.searchProduct =function(productTBSearched){      
    $scope.TBFProduct=productTBSearched;
    if($location.path() === "/SearchProducts") {
        $route.reload();
    } else {
        $location.path("/SearchProducts");
    }
}
```

Comment: It resolved the issue. Thank you very much for your prompt response.